# javascript timer/duration giving wrong calculation after while

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, timer

couple of days ago, I found a [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) code which I thought that I can use it to calculate the login time for users.. but after tested it in my application, I found that there's a difference in time after while. So, I decided to use an [chrome](/questions/tagged/chrome) extension called "[Staying Alive for Google Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/staying-alive-for-google/lhobbakbeomfcgjallalccfhfcgleinm)", it worked perfectly "or that I was hoping to.. and to be honest, it kinda good", but after that I found the same problem as picture attached.
 [image]

and here's code for [javscript](/questions/tagged/javscript) I found:

```
/*===============*/

var seconds = 0; 
var minutes = 0;
var hours = 0;
var t;

function add() {
    seconds++;
    if (seconds >= 60) {
        seconds = 0;
        minutes++;
        if (minutes >= 60) {
            minutes = 0;
            hours++;
        }
    }

    $('#totalTime').html ( "" + (hours ? (hours > 9 ? hours : "0" + hours) : "00") + ":" + (minutes ? (minutes > 9 ? minutes : "0" + minutes) : "00") + ":" + (seconds > 9 ? seconds : "0" + seconds) );

    timer();
}

function timer() {
    t = setTimeout(add, 1000);
}
/*===============*/
```

So, I hope that someone can help me, how to make timer run decently, or has a better solution, because I have **more than 6 timers** in this page..

**P.S.** this application coded using [php](/questions/tagged/php) and [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) and I've an [ajax](/questions/tagged/ajax) call every 5000 milliseconds running in same page.

**P.P.S.** one of my friends suggested [webworkers](/questions/tagged/webworkers) , but I really don't know a lot about it.

thanks a lot

Comment: When your question is solved, mark the answer with ✓.

Comment: the question has already been answered but since you already have an ajax call every 5 seconds, why not just mark that server-side and return a value then to sync with your javascript counter?  You can also save that data at that time if it is of use to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to measure time is to save the value of the system clock (provided by Date-Object) at start and subtract it from the current timestamp.

An example:

```js
const totalTime = document.querySelector('#totalTime');
const startTime = Date.now();

function updateClock() {
  // JS Date counts in ms, divide by 1000 to get seconds
  // |0 does the same as Math.floor(value)
  const elapsedTime = (Date.now() - startTime) / 1000 |0;
  const seconds = elapsedTime % 60;
  const minutes = Math.floor(elapsedTime / 60) % 60;
  const hours = Math.floor(elapsedTime / 3600) % 24;
  
  totalTime.textContent = 
    (hours < 10 ? '0' : '') + hours + ':' +
    (minutes < 10 ? '0' : '') + minutes + ':' +
    (seconds < 10 ? '0' : '') + seconds;
}

window.setInterval(updateClock, 1000);
```

```html
<div id="totalTime"></div>
```

**EDIT 1 "from the one who asked":**

I did some edits to your code cos I needed to add some options (reset, pause and resume).
I thought it could help any one, so I post it...

```js
class Clock {
 constructor(element, offset = 0) {
  if(!(element && element instanceof HTMLElement))
   throw new Error('Parameter element must be a valid HTML Element');
  
  this._startTime = 0;
  this._offset = offset;
  this._interval = null;
  this._element = element;
 }

 tick() {
  const elapsedTime = (Date.now() - this._startTime) / 1000 |0;
  const seconds = elapsedTime % 60;
  const minutes = elapsedTime / 60 % 60 |0;
  const hours = elapsedTime / 3600 % 24 |0;
  
  this._element.textContent = 
   (hours < 10 ? '0' : '') + hours + ':' +
   (minutes < 10 ? '0' : '') + minutes + ':' +
   (seconds < 10 ? '0' : '') + seconds;
 }

 pause () {
  if(this._interval) {
   this._offset = Date.now() - this._startTime;
   window.clearInterval(this._interval);
   this._interval = null;
  }
 }

 resume () {
  if(!this._interval) {
   this._startTime = Date.now() - this._offset;
   this._interval = setInterval(this.tick.bind(this), 1000);
   this.tick();
  }
 }

 reset () {
  this.pause();
  this._offset = 0;
  this._element.textContent = '00:00:00';
 }
};

let clock = new Clock(document.querySelector('#totalTime'), 30000);
document.querySelector('#pause').addEventListener('click', () => { clock.pause() });
document.querySelector('#resume').addEventListener('click', () => { clock.resume() });
document.querySelector('#reset').addEventListener('click', () => { clock.reset() });
clock.resume();
```

```html
<div id="totalTime"></div>
<button id="pause">Pause</button>
<button id="resume">Resume</button>
<button id="reset">Reset</button>
```

Comment: great, thanks.. but I've a question please, How to pause/resume/reset this timer?

Comment: and what if I need it to continue on the previous value (time) in "totalTime" div.. for example if I got the time from server side and it was 01:05:45 , hwo to make your function start counting from 01:05:46 .. 47 ..48 ..etc?

Comment: @Hossam I've updated your contribution a bit (including time-offset).

Answer (score 2):

This behaviour is expected due to the fact JavaScript is executed in a single thread in the browser. Basically, the delay amount of the setTimeout and setInterval functions should be considered a *minimum*.

For example, if you would execute a function resulting in heavy DOM manipulation, this could postpone the execution of the callback.

For more information on this topic, read John Resig's post [on the the execution order of JavaScript timers](https://johnresig.com/blog/how-javascript-timers-work/).

Your friend's suggestion could provide a solution as [WebWorkers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API) are executed in a different thread and hence are less subjective to blocking DOM manipulation. However, I would suggest you'd handle the time calculation on the server side. For example by creating an entry for the stream in a database containing at least the start date and time of the stream. Then either:

1. Let your JavaScript application poll the server to sync the time
2. Alternatively and preferably, set up a streaming connection using a [WebSocket](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API).

Comment: it's great idea, thanks a lot, I'll go with your 1st suggest: "server side sync". till I can work on **WebSocket** and I'll switch to it, to reduce requests from Ajax calls... thanks again, really appreciated